# Difference between WMTS vector tile calls to GeoServer

Tags: wmts

I'm using Leaflet to call vector tiles from GeoServer. Within WMTS, I've found 2 formats which I'm not sure what makes them different. I understnad that they make the same call, but am unsure why one would have "service" and "rest" (#1) and the other just "service" (#2, which seems like a REST call anyway) in the URL.

1. The WMTS *REST* Service (which I was able to track down from the GetCapabilities):

```
http://localhost:8000/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/city:roads/{style}/EPSG:900913/EPSG:900913:{z}/{y}/{x}?format=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile
```

2. The WMTS Service (I just found this structure online somewhere):

```
http://localhost:8000/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYER=city:roads&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}
```

Is there a particular preference between these, or are they different ways of doing the same thing? They seem to be to both be REST calls, render the same in my Leaflet app, and when I put them in my URL, GeoServer returns an `.application` file for both.

Comment: please read the standard - https://www.ogc.org/standard/wmts/

Comment: Neither of them are REST, there's no such thing as a RESTful URL, they are just different URL templating mechanisms.

Comment: Ok thanks. Looks like they are just ways of implementing the same call (as you @nmtoken said in this other thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455362/calling-vector-tiles-served-from-geoserver-in-leaflet). It's just that the WMTS supports the RESTful interface as well as the KVP (an acronym which confusingly for beginners isn't defined in the standard) "in an effort to harmonize this interface standard with the OSGeo specification".

Comment: The section 8 of the standard does tell you `...service requests made using lists of parameters and their values defined as lists of Key-Value Pairs (KVP) `  but for wider description you should look at OWS Common (common components for OGC web service standards) ~ https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=38867